mysqlclient not found even after installed in Django on MacOS
I use pyenv to create a virtual-env, and install mysqlclient in it successfully. But when I python manage.py runserver, it shows 'Did you install mysqlclient?'. How to resoleve it? I try it both in terminal and PyCharm, all did not work. I also looked up a lot of technical forums and basically said that the virtual environment mismatch is the reason, and no one is in the same situation as me.


Could you please give more context, which pip install command you used, to install the mysqlclient in virtual environment.

have you installed mysql-client
$ # Assume you are activating Python 3 venv $ brew install mysql-client pkg-config $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig" $ pip install mysqlclient
https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/
